# Custom aggregation to a JSON in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my current table:

| User Id | Product | Amount 1 | Amount 2 | Amount 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| 1 | B | 200 | 300 | 400 |
| 2 | A | 500 | 600 | 700 |

This is the output I'm looking for:

| User Id | Amount 1 | Amount 2 | Amount 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"A": 100, "B": 200} | {"A": 200, "B": 300} | {"A": 300, "B": 400} |
| 2 | {"A": 500} | {"A": 600} | {"A": 700} |

I understand that I should be using a User Defined Aggregate Function, but am unable to understand how to implement them via PySpark.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `to_json` after grouping by `User Id` and creating map column:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.groupBy("User Id").agg(*[
    F.to_json(
        F.map_from_entries(F.collect_list(F.struct(F.col("Product"), F.col(c))))
    ).alias(c)
    for c in df.columns[2:]
])

df1.show()
#+-------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
#|User Id|         Amount 1|         Amount 2|         Amount 3|
#+-------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
#|      1|{"A":100,"B":200}|{"A":200,"B":300}|{"A":300,"B":400}|
#|      2|        {"A":500}|        {"A":600}|        {"A":700}|
#+-------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```